# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out, from one day to another without code change

Tags: android, url, socketexception

I got an app in GooglePlay, **it is publicated about 6 months ago**, and it is **worked well** everytime **until today.**

***Without any code modification*** from one day to another i got **this error:**

```
12-07 14:51:09.646: W/System.err(23695): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
12-07 14:51:09.673: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
12-07 14:51:09.673: W/System.err(23695):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
12-07 14:51:09.677: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
12-07 14:51:09.677: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
12-07 14:51:09.677: W/System.err(23695):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1002)
12-07 14:51:09.681: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:75)
12-07 14:51:09.681: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
12-07 14:51:09.681: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
12-07 14:51:09.685: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
12-07 14:51:09.689: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
12-07 14:51:09.689: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
12-07 14:51:09.689: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
12-07 14:51:09.689: W/System.err(23695):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
12-07 14:51:09.692: W/System.err(23695):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
12-07 14:51:09.696: W/System.err(23695):    at com.MyPackageName.XML.MyDownloadingTask.doInBackground(MyDownloadingTask.java:95)
12-07 14:51:09.696: W/System.err(23695):    at com.MyPackageName.XML.MyDownloadingTask.doInBackground(MyDownloadingTask.java:1)
12-07 14:51:09.704: W/System.err(23695):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-07 14:51:09.708: W/System.err(23695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-07 14:51:09.708: W/System.err(23695):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-07 14:51:09.708: W/System.err(23695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-07 14:51:09.708: W/System.err(23695):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-07 14:51:09.708: W/System.err(23695):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

**I did not changed a single line in my code** and now my app is not working. It is related to an url connection at startup so now it does nothing for this silly, *appear-from-nowhere* error.

From a browser i can reach the wanted url so the server is repsonsible...

Please, if anyone know what is it help me.
Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networks and servers are unreliable.  Your code could be perfect, and you may still encounter networks that lose packets or servers that fail to respond quickly enough.

Comment: So what is the solution? Maybe we need to apply another safeguard source on timeouts? This app needs this url connection at every startup.

Comment: How do you want your app to behave if the network is unavailable or the remote server is slow/down?  Should it retry indefinitely?  Print an error and give up?  You should definitely handle errors like this at the beginning of a connection, and during the middle of a connection.